# Выполнение высоконагруженного скрипта при ограничении времени

Tags: php

Предположим, есть скрипт на `PHP`, выполняющий большой объем работы (например, парсер), скажем, в течение нескольких часов. При этом на хостинге есть определенные ограничения, например `max_execution_time` выставлено в `600`, и повысить нельзя. Интересуют способы реализации, которые позволят обойти ограничение по времени.

1. Есть свой велосипед, который отправляет `AJAX` запросы, а скрипт обрабатывает только часть данных (например, парсит только 10 страниц). За счет использования `js` можно всякие прогресс-бары докручивать. Интересует, есть ли какие-то готовые решения подобной проблемы или примеры реализации
2. А если нужно скрипт по `cron`-у запускать, то вариант с `js` уже не пойдет...

В общем, какие есть варианты? Есть готовые примеры, библиотеки?

Comment: Решать такие задачи с использованием php это очень печально. Варианты: очереди сообщений, (псевдо)многопоточное выполнение кода в php, выкинуть php и все переписать на perl/python/c/c++/java/...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Оставаясь в рамках условий, единственный вариант – бить большую задачу на много мелких. Раз в 5 минут кроном запускать «рабочий» процесс, который посмотрит, не работает ли ещё его предыдущий собрат, и если горит зелёный свет, то начнёт работу: «так, что тут у нас на очереди?» – и выполнит очередной маленький кусок работы.

Крон запускает задачи, самое частое, раз в 5 минут. Сложность оптимизации – минимизировать время простоя. Приблизиться по времени выполнения к 5 (10, 15, .. 5*i) минутам, но не превысить их, чтобы следующий запущенный скрипт сразу увидел зелёный свет.

Уточните возможности хостинга – может, получится запускать несколько «рабочих» параллельно. Тогда придётся продумать параллелизм. Вообще хостинги с описанными ограничениями, часто ещё и ограничивают число процессов и память, поэтому особенно там не разгуляешься. На `hc.ru` ещё можно было как-то оптимизировать – выключить веб-сервер, или заменить apache на nginx. Но это всё довольно ограниченно.

Прогресс можно сообщать, обновляя файл на диске или запись в БД. А веб-клиент пусть просто поллит ajax'ом раз в секунду скрипт, который этот прогресс ему сообщит.

**Если выйти за рамки** – то возьмите уже собственный (виртуальный) сервер за несколько баксов в месяц, и гоняйте его по полной. Напр. [на DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=3920ff7427c3) минимальная коробка стоит $5 в месяц. По этой моей реф. ссылке вы получите на свой счёт сразу десять – хватит на два месяца погонять, попробовать.

Answer (score -1):

Тоже криво, но можно через `socket` или `file_get_contents` пустить скрипт в рекурсию.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?